# How to loop through loaded KML in maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I need to get markers, overlays and etc, that were loaded from KML, but i don't understand how.
Here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/umapper/YCfHEWaCxMc is written that i can loop through KMLayer. but i can't!

I loading KML that way:

```
var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.searcharoo.net/SearchKml/newyork.kml", { suppressInfoWindows: true, map: map });
```

Then i don't see anyway to find what objects inside. I tried to look in debugger what **nyLayer** contain inside, but nothing like objects array. Also tried this:

```
var test = nyLayer[0];
```

But **test** is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the Placemarks in a KmlLayer other than by using a click listener.

You can access them if you use a third party parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/), but then you lose the advantage of the KmlLayer's tile based rendering, so you will see performance degradation for large numbers of objects.

[Example which creates a dynamic sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?type=m&filename=cta.xml) using geoxml3